# How can Ora-24309 happen while connection-state is closed?

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odp.net

```
//I got a Connection which is kept alive..
IDbConnection con = CreatyMyOracleConnection();

//Later, if I want to use the connection i check if it's closed to (re-)open it.'
if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    con.Open() // Here OracleException 24309 is thrown
```

Sometimes i'm getting an:

> ORA-24309 "already connected to a server".

How can this be if check the state before opening?

A try/catch seems like an ugly solution. There should be a way to recognize what to do with a connection, I think.
How should I check the connection before (re-)opening it?

I'm currently using unmanaged ODP.Net 11.2.

Answer (score 1):

`ConnectionState` can be

- Broken
- Closed
- Connecting
- Executing
- Fetching
- Open

see [ConnectionState Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.connectionstate?view=netframework-4.7.2)

So, you may better use

```
if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    con.Open();
```

Comment: This is why i check if it IS closed. Only if it is closed i'm opening it. I got some more code around this snippet to handle other problems, but I thought: `ConnectionState.Closed` => `I'm allowed to Open it`

Comment: Perhaps a temporary try-catch that logs the actual connection state when `Open()` fails would clear this up.